# Who are the other 2 Taijutsu fighters that Kisame acknowledged?

Tags: naruto

I was rewatching the episode when Guy fought Kisame. Kisame said that taijutsu fighter like Guy is rare, but he knows two more.

Who is he talking about?
 Episode 250 at 19:25 to 19:43

Answer (score 5):

Based on a bit of Googling, that line is a mistranslation. The actual intended meaning of Kisame's line is, ["Though this is the third time I'm facing you..."](https://www.narutoforums.org/posts/36922634/) (It literally translates to something like "For me, it's the third time," but the intended meaning is clearer in context.)

The three times they fight:

1. [When Itachi and Kisame show up to first try to kidnap Naruto](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kisame_Hoshigaki#Search_for_Tsunade):

> Kisame accompanied Itachi to Konoha to help kidnap Naruto Uzumaki. After the two gained attention due to their unusual clothing, they were stopped by Asuma Sarutobi and Kurenai Yūhi. Asuma and Kurenai found themselves outmatched, but Kakashi arrived to help balance the odds. Asuma was able to distract Kisame while Itachi fought Kakashi. He waited patiently for Itachi's fight to finish, but before Itachi delivered the final blow, Kakashi remembered Jiraiya's warning and recognised the duo as members of Akatsuki from their black cloaks. Itachi changed his mind and ordered Kisame to kidnap Kakashi and kill Asuma and Kurenai. Before he could do so, however, Might Guy showed up and kicked an attacking Kisame in the face. Following Guy's arrival, Itachi ordered Kisame to retreat, not wanting to start a large-scale battle. Kisame seemed quite annoyed with Itachi's idea, as he desperately wanted to fight the Konoha shinobi.

2. [While Akatsuki is extracting Shukaku (the One-Tailed Beast) from Gaara's body](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kisame_Hoshigaki#Kazekage_Rescue_Mission):

> While Akatsuki extracted the One-Tailed Shukaku from Gaara's body, they learned that Team Guy was nearing their location. Remembering his last encounter with Guy, Kisame volunteered to keep them occupied while the sealing was completed. Nagato used the Shapeshifting Technique to make a duplicate of Kisame's body that would be remotely controlled by Kisame. The clone located and confronted Team Guy, but was disappointed that Guy didn't remember him. He converts the surrounding desert into a lake to give him a battlefield advantage and attacks Team Guy. After numerous attempts Team Guy made attacking Kisame, Guy managed to separate him from Samehada, leading to the rest of his team launching an assault. Kisame swiftly made water clones to block their attacks and immediately used the Water Prison Technique to imprison them.
>
>  Guy then attempted to attack Kisame with his own sword but Samehada intervened and returned to its owner. Now that it was a one on one fight, Kisame directed all his attention towards Guy leading him to use his nunchaku. After exchanging blows with each other, Kisame overpowered Guy, launching him to the bottom of the newly formed lake. Seeing that he had the geographical advantage, Kisame repeatedly attacked Guy until he was forced to open the sixth gate. Doing so, Guy forced away the surrounding water and immediately attacked Kisame, sending him flying into the air, giving an opportunity for him to use his Morning Peacock technique to end the fight, resulting in Kisame's clone being killed. Afterwards Kisame voiced his regret to Itachi that their clones only had 30% of their chakra and thus were not as powerful as their actual selves. Ultimately, however, the two accomplished their task of delaying the two teams long enough for the rest of the Akatsuki to extract Shukaku from Gaara.

3. The third time, of course, is the scene you're talking about. Kisame pretends to have been defeated by Killer B, and hides inside his sword Samehada (which Killer B takes as his own) to infiltrate the Hidden Cloud Village (Kumogakure), but [he is discovered](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kisame_Hoshigaki#Fourth_Shinobi_World_War:_Countdown):

> To protect them from Akatsuki, B and Naruto Uzumaki were sent to the island in the Land of Lightning. After B helped Naruto to tame the Nine-Tails, Naruto was able to sense Kisame's hatred within Samehada, despite his and Samehada's identical chakra. Discovered and outnumbered, Kisame took Samehada and tried to escape, but Naruto used the new speed granted to him by the Nine-Tails to stop him. Naruto was so fast, in fact, that his foot got stuck in a wall, allowing Kisame to continue his bid for freedom. As soon as he exited the Falls of Truth he ran into and was attacked by Might Guy, who believed Kisame was his inner self. Although Guy realised Kisame was not his inner self, he still didn't remember him, instead believing him to be a blowfish. Samehada abandoned Kisame and returned to Killer B. Kisame stole some chakra from the both of them to revitalise him after being within Samehada for so long. Aoba Yamashiro tried to neutralise him with Secret Technique: Stone Needles, but this only enabled Kisame to absorb his chakra as well.
>
>  Kisame then swam away and tried to make it off the island, and when he reached the shoreline, Kisame summoned a shark and gave it a scroll filled with the information he had gathered. Guy tracked him down and, seeing what Kisame was doing, tried to stop the shark. Kisame then used Water Release: A Thousand Feeding Sharks to conceal it and overwhelm Guy. When Guy's Morning Peacock couldn't destroy all of the sharks, he opened the seventh chakra gate, blocking the sharks' route. To get rid of Guy, Kisame used Water Release: Great Shark Bullet Technique, and Guy countered with his Daytime Tiger. Although the Great Shark Bullet grows stronger when used against chakra-based attacks, Daytime Tiger was composed of "youthful" air pressure. It overpowered and defeated Kisame, as well as destroyed all of the remaining sharks. Though defeated, Kisame was annoyed that Guy still could not remember him and tried to continue fighting, but was knocked unconscious by Guy.
>
>  After returning to the island, Yamato restrained Kisame to allow Aoba to read his mind in order to gather intelligence on Akatsuki. When Aoba came across memories of Tobi's face and his promises of ending the "world of lies", Kisame bit his own tongue to force himself awake and broke free of his restraints. The Kumo and Konoha-nin tried to subdue him, but Kisame trapped himself with the Water Prison Technique. Before he was completely immobilised, he summoned three sharks and allowed them to devour him. Within his final moments he remembered his first meeting with Itachi and realised that he was not as terrible as he once thought, as he was willing to give his life to protect the cause he believed in and died with a smile on his face. This act of conviction caused Guy to gain new respect for his adversary and vowed to always remember him. He and the others then attempted to read the scroll that Kisame tried so hard to send, but found that it was booby-trapped; they were each caught in a Water Prison with a shark. Another shark took the scroll and swam away with it, which eventually found its way to Zetsu.